# Fail to ping/ssh from single machine to another specific machine

Tags: ssh, ip, ping, local-area-network, connection

I'm using Google Cloud, there are 2 machines on the cloud which can't ping each other, A can't ping B, and B can't ping A too; all other machines can ping to A&B as usual. **But it happens only on Internet IPs, not LAN IPs.***

The difference is this way:

```
#fails, timeout
ping 35.197.x.x #internet ips

#ok as normal
ping 10.240.x.x #LAN ips on google cloud
```

I have disabled Google Cloud firewall, firewalld service, iptables, ufw; still no luck. Why is it so?

When running 'netstat -nc' on the listener server, it keeps showing **SYN_RECV** and never ESTABLISHED.

```
#test ssh connection from A to B,
#run netstat on B:
netstat -nc | grep IP_OF_A
```

And on the client (originator, the one which starts the connection), netstat keeps showing only **SYN_SENT**; this means 'SYN+ACK' packet has never been sent back to client, but how to solve this problem?